# the firm of Bartlett, Caryoe & Company was a large and prosperous house, and Drouet stood well

Tags: meaning, phrases

The following is a quote from Sister Carrie by Theodore Dreiser

> Hurstwood liked Drouet. The latter's genial nature and dressy appearance pleased him. He knew that Drouet was only a travelling salesman—and not one of many years at that—but the firm of Bartlett, Caryoe & Company was a large and prosperous house, and Drouet **stood well**. Hurstwood knew Caryoe quite well, having drunk a glass now and then with him, in company with several others, when the conversation was general.

It would be very much appreciated if you can tell me what is the meaning of "stood well" in bold?

Comment: '[Stood well](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stand+well+with) with them' would be more usual.

Comment: My guess reading that would be that it's related to "being in [good standing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/good_standing)", but I've never seen it worded that way before. Perhaps someone with more knowledge of 19th Century American English could confirm.

Comment: @IMSoP: I'm not familiar with the exact cited usage myself, but your ***to be in good standing*** (well-regarded, trustworthy) sounds far more likely than what initially came to mind for me *(he **carries / comports** himself well / appropriately / confidently)*.

Comment: I believe this is more about physical posture rather than what kind of attitude he presents.

Comment: I think it probably means something like "is in good standing".  The "physical posture" reading would be very odd: the author was just talking about how Bartlett, Caryoe & Company is large and prosperous, and suddenly we're talking about how Drouet has good posture?

Answer (score 2):

"Stood well" in that usage generally means "had a good reputation". It can also mean "was relatively prosperous"  It mean mean "stood well with the firm", that is that Drouet  had a good reputation with his bosses, and perhaps his co-workers also.  Or it may mean that he stood well with the general public, that is that is reputation was good among those who knew him. The phrase  "stood well" is most usually followed by "with" to indicate in whose mind the person stands well, that is who thinks well of the person. To say that "A stands well with B" means that B thinks well of A.

I should mention that *Sister Carrie* is old enough that some idioms and usages have changed since it was written, and some care is needed in using it as a guide to current English-language usage.